# PHP failed to submit the html form

Tags: javascript, php, html, xmlhttprequest

below is simple PHP script to validate and successfully submit the form to the server I've added xhr(XMLHttpRequest) to make it efficient.First it was supposed to check if the input fields are empty then show error message , if password does not meet criteria then show error message  but i am wondering why it does not work like it was expected , when i click submit button it submit the form and none of the functionalities works . any help will be appreciated

```
    <?php
require_once('db.php');
error_reporting(~E_NOTICE);
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Nairobi');
// Log errors to a file
ini_set('error_log', '/var/log/php_errors.log');

// Initialize error message array
$errMsg = array();

if(isset($_POST['register'])){
    $name = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = filter_var($_POST['password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $time=date('y-m-d h:i:s',time());
    $date=date('y-m-d',strtotime('now'));
    
    // validate inputs and Display user-friendly error messages
    if (empty($name) || empty($password)) {
        // Display error message to the user
        $errMsg[] = "Enter both name and password";
    } else{
        // Implement password complexity rules
        if (strlen($password) < 8 || !preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $password) || !preg_match("#[A-Z]+#", $password) || !preg_match("#[a-z]+#", $password) || !preg_match("#[\W]+#", $password)) {
            $errMsg[]="Password must contain at least 8 characters including uppercase and lowercase letters, numbers, and symbols";
        } else {
            // Use a custom salt instead of the default salt
            $custom_salt = bin2hex(random_bytes(10));
            // Use password_hash() function to create a password hash
            $hash = password_hash($password . $custom_salt, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
            
            // Insert user details into database
            if(empty($errMsg)){
                $sth=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(name,password,time,date) VALUES(:name,:password,:time,:date)");
                $sth->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $sth->bindParam(':password', $hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $sth->bindParam(':time', $time, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $sth->bindParam(':date', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $sth->execute();
                die('success');
            }
        }
    }
}
?>

<!-- HTML code starts here -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>User Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>User Registration Form</h2>
    <?php 
    // Display error messages
    if (!empty($errMsg)) {
        foreach ($errMsg as $msg) {
            echo '<div style="color: red;">' . $msg . '</div>';
        }
    }
    ?>
    <div id="error-message" style="color: red;"></div>

<form id="register-form" action="" method="post">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br><br>
        
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
        
        <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register">
    </form>
    <script>
  const form = document.getElementById('register-form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent the default form submission
    
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
          // successful response, redirect to the index page
          window.location.href = 'index.php';
        } else {
          // display the error message to the user
          const errMsg = document.getElementById('error-message');
          errMsg.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
      }
    };
    xhr.open('POST', form.action);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send(new FormData(form));
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: PHP does not "submit" your form data to the server - it processes the form data that was _received_ on the server side.

Comment: why are you appending a random `salt` to the `$password` rather than as part of the `options` parameter for `password_hash`?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius For info from the manual `Warning - The salt option is deprecated. It is now preferred to simply use the salt that is generated by default. As of PHP 8.0.0, an explicitly given salt is ignored.`
`

Comment: That extra salt will make it pretty hard to verify the hash, since you're adding a random salt to the original value, but never store that salt anywhere. To be able to match a password against that password hash, you would need to add that salt to the password before verifying it against the hash, or it will never match. There's no reason for managing your own salt at all here. `password_hash()` will handle it for you.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - OK but appending what is intended as the salt `$custom_salt` to the posted `password` and then hashing it will create a hash that will not be validated later using `password_verify` surely?

Comment: Ok, @ProfessorAbronsius we are talking at cross purposes :) I thought you were suggesting OP should append the randon salt to the Options. Obviously you were not :) So I think we were both saying the same thing, which would be DONT add that randon Salt. It would make the password permanantly useless

Comment: @RiggsFolly - yep, exactly. **If** a salt is to be included ( & agreed - it should be left to PHP to do this for us ) it should be within the options argument and not concatenated to the posted password value prior to hashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least two different problems here, each of which would cause your problem by itself.

## Your content-type is wrong

> ```
> xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
> xhr.send(new FormData(form));
> ```

Under normal circumstances, when you pass a `FormData` object to `send()` then XHR will generate a `Content-Type` request header from it with the correct content type (multipart form data with a boundary parameter).

In this case  you've overridden the `Content-Type` header to one that is wrong. PHP tries to parse the body as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, fails, and doesn't populate `$_POST`.

---

## Your submit button is unsuccessful

> ```
> isset($_POST['register'])
> ```

When you submit a form normally, the clicked submit button becomes a successful control (i.e. sends its name and value in the form data).

You're intercepting the normal form submission (and preventing it with `event.preventDefault();`) and constructing a new request using Ajax.

`new FormData(form)` will **not** include the submit button's data, so you can't use it to branch your code with an `if` statement as you are attempting.

Comment: re-write the code to implement the correction you've mentioned above

Comment: @willy — I'm not being paid enough to do that.

Comment: @willy - surely you can incorporate the above into your codebase rather than asking for someone else to not only identify the issue but write corrected code too?

Comment: @Professor Abronsius just for learning purpose only

Comment: If you read the answer an attempt to apply the changes yourself (instead of being spoon-fed some copypasta) then you're more likely to learn something.